# What settings (if any) control the firing of the logic app CRM record created or updated trigger?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I have two logic apps with a "When a record is created or update" trigger on a CRM entity; one on Tasks, one on People.

The Tasks trigger fires Ok, but the People one doesn't with either new or updated records.

Checked the JSON of each of them for the trigger and they look OK ...

```
"path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('xxx.crm4'))}/tables/
   @{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('tasks'))}/onupdateditems"

"path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('xxx.crm4'))}/tables/
   @{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('common_persons'))}/onupdateditems"
```

So is there something in Dynamics that has to be enabled for logic app triggers to work?

**UPDATE:** the built-in entities, e.g. Accounts and Tasks work.
But any of our custom entities, e.g. Person and Supplier, doesn't seem to trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the setting **Change Tracking** was not enabled for your custom entities. Verify that.

You should get an error like [explained in this blog](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/procrm/archive/2018/06/08/logic-app-error-entity-xy-entity-isn-t-enabled-for-change-tracking). Not sure why you are not seeing that error.

> Entity: xxxx isn’t enabled for change tracking

Comment: That sorted it ... but it's weird that was a significant delay between activating the change tracking, and logic app triggers working ... they didn't work when I enabled and tried a few things, but I got something next day